# How to check if an element is after another element using PrototypeJS?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li class="test">Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I attempted:

```
 $$('ul.tabs > li').each(function(item,index){
       if ($(item).isAfter(".test")){
           alert(1);
       }
 });
```

but this clearly does not work.

I want to add to all list items which are after the element with class *test* .  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize [Element.previousSiblings](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/previousSiblings/)

```
$$('ul.tabs li').each(function(item,index){
     if (item.previousSiblings().any(siblingHasClassTest)){
       alert(1);
     }
});
function siblingHasClassTest(sibling) { 
  return sibling.hasClassName('test');
}
```

For a demonstration, see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XC3V3cI0sQDF1ZVA4EKk) or the snippet below.

```js
function findItems() {
  $$('ul.tabs > li').each(function(item, index) {
    if (item.previousSiblings().any(siblingHasClassTest)) {
      //alert(1);
      $('debug').innerHTML += 'element after test - index: ' + index + '<br />';
    }
  });
}

function siblingHasClassTest(sibling) {
  return sibling.hasClassName('test');
}
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', findItems);
```

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="prototype@*" data-semver="1.7.1+0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

and perhaps you could utilize [Function#curry()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/curry/) to simplify that siblingHasClasstest